# Run PHP Script on Button Click in Background (Regardless of User Page Change, or Browser Exit)

Tags: php, ajax, cron, background, queue

I have a script that parses a large amount of historical data through MySQL queries and other PHP manipulation.

Essentially it is a "Order Report" generator that outputs a lot of data and forms it into an array, and then finally encoding it into json and saving it on my server.

I would like to optimize these more, but to generate a 30 day report takes about 10-15 seconds, 90 days takes 45-seconds to a minute to complete, 180 days anywhere from 2-3 minutes, and for an entire year it takes typically over 5 minutes for the script to finish.

Like eBay and Amazon, I am thinking, due to loading times, a 'File Queue' system is needed, as the user isn't going to want to wait 5 minutes in a loading scenario waiting for a yearly report.

I understand about ajax requests, and how this can be done, or have even read about hidden iframes that perform the request. My concern is, what if the user changes the page (if normal ajax request), or exits the browser, the script execution will not finish.

My only other thought would be to possibly have a cron job along with a MySQL table that inserts the users request, but thinking forward the CRON would have to run about once every minute, all day, every single day, non-stop to check if a report request was issued.

This seems plausible, but perhaps not ideal as having a cron run every minute 24/7/365 seems it'd produce a bit of baggage in its continuity (especially since reports being generated would not be conducted very often).

Can anyone recommend/suggest a route of action to take that won't be a burden to my server, and will still run and complete regardless of user action?

Comment: Post results off `EXPLAIN <query>`  foreach query for are using and `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` for each table involved here and off cource the used queries here. ?  MySQL should be to handle billions off records just fine when tables and indexes are designed correctly and the SQL code is written good..

Comment: .. posting some PHP code also might also proof very usefull as for now this question is all full off question marks which makes it impossible for us to answer or to  recommend/suggest  optimisation steps....  .

Comment: Okay, lemme see.. It is a fairly intensive script.  The MySQL queries are not the main culprit.  To get a years worth of order data the query itself only takes about 5 seconds when executed standalone.  Returns about 100,000 rows.  The main reason for the long-running time is I am needing to loop through each row and construct a new array based off this to finally get a properly formatted array (or json file, rather).  Was mostly looking for suggestions on how to run in the background, not optimizing so that this is not needed.. so I am not sure exactly what code to share that may help.

Comment: Fair enough thats why posting more code or a better information is important so we know what happens on your server.. You could try with PHP's [Connection handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) by the way just thought about it it was a thing in PHP..   There are functions to  detect and ignore the disconnect from a http client (like a browser) and continue execution..  That was basically the main point off your question..

Comment: Woah, it's really that easy? I can just run a PHP script through an ajax button click and include `ignore_user_abort();` so that it finishes regardless? Never ran into this function. Thank you still looking into.

Comment: *"Woah, it's really that easy? I can just run a PHP script through an ajax button click and include ignore_user_abort(); so that it finishes regardless?"* Well easy??? Be aware with session stats when using this you might need to manally use `session_write_close()` ...

Comment: Thank you I am reading up a bunch on this. Won't `session_write_close()` also log whoever is logged in out? I believe I was using that before and that was the case as my authentication method is reliant on session data.  I am going to have to read more into this though because I do not understand how sessions are related to php background script execution...

Comment: This might be a dead question, but I really appreciate the suggestions.  If you want to give a generic answer type thing stating what you told me about ignore_user_abort() and maybe a bit about sessions I will accept and close.  If not no big deal, just saying, have to read more into this

Comment: i don't feel PHP connection handling is the correct approach to handle this so skip writing a answer about it, yes it might be the most easy to implement and test...Anyhow  *" The main reason for the long-running time is I am needing to loop through each row and construct a new array based off this to finally get a properly formatted array (or json file, rather)"* MySQL can directly format JSON from records and export it to file on disk or send it to PHP if needed most likey you can skip that complete need for array construction and looping in PHP..  ...

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right.  It may not be the best approach (and I realize that -- looking into my long-drawn loop it can be optimized substantially).. notably I am taking the 100,000 or so rows, and taking the single row `OrderIdentifier`, putting this into a PHP array and then using `array_column($getprevioussales, 'OrderIdentifier');` along with `join("','", $neworderidarray);` to do a ridiculous `IN` clause that is so long it's ridiculous. I'm definitely aware this can be optimized (probably a temporary table for `IN` clause, or possible join on original query)... it works but it's bad

Comment: Just saying this question as stated probably has no real answer aside from that, or similar... My code optimization itself was kind of secondary to the stated question...  Sorry I knew it couldn't elicit an actual definite response this question, was really looking for suggestions.  Thank you once more, that's all :)

Comment: large list in MySQL in the `IN()` is bad news yes.. `column IN()` is syntax suger for `column = ? OR column = ? OR [, ... ]` MySQL does to very poor job optimisating OR conditions most likely requires a FULL scan then anyhow even with a small/medium size list ..  Like you say it better optimized  with a JOIN or a `UNION ALL` (how Oracle DB does it internally) it

Comment: Yes I was up late last night realizing this approach was not ideal whatsoever (originally code was used to get a single day, so that was no problem), but getting into hundreds of days, I realize now this is pretty much a necessity. It is tough getting everything optimized with due dates, etc.  Still not sure if doing this will cut my script down to a user-friendly wait time to get report and not require some type of background script to generate file, but much appreciate the talk and insight on this-- was obviously bothering me and you helped clear my mind up a bit about it.

Comment: thats way i always test mine applications with real live expected datasizes with a factor lets say 30%/40% on top off it.. if some table could have millions or records i program and test it with those sizes.. Then you can never really be fully surprised how it will perform in the future when datasizes grow as you have a general idea..